# How to union 2 string arrays, but keep the duplicate in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, union

```
s1={"phone","smartphone","dumpphone"} (all string elements in s1 are unique)
s2={"phone","phone","smartphone"}
```

(string elements in s2 can be duplicated, but each element in s2 must belongs to s1, i.e. s2 can not contain string that does not exist in s1. For example, s2 can not contain "handheld" because s1 does not contain ""handheld"")

```
s2 union s1={"phone","phone", "smartphone","dumpphone"}
```

Set & HashSet didn't allow duplicate

I tried List but it didn't help.

Do you know how to solve?

Comment: What was wrong with a List implementation?  Seems fine provided you conditionally insert items into the union list according to your logic.

Answer (score 1):

A List implementation should work fine.  Here's your code using an ArrayList:

```
String[] s1 = new String[]{"phone","smartphone","dumpphone"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"phone","phone","smartphone"};

ArrayList<String> union = new ArrayList<>();
// Add elements of s1
for(String s : s1){ union.add(s); }
// Conditionally add elements of s2
for(String s : s2){ if(union.contains(s)){ union.add(s); } }
```

Results:

```
for(String s : union){ System.out.println(s); }
```

Prints

```
phone
smartphone
dumpphone
phone
phone
smartphone
```

Note: You say that you're expecting only two occurances of "phone".  Why?  From your problem statement it's not clear.

**EDIT:**

As per @dantuch's comment below, you may be looking for something like this instead:

```
String[] s1 = new String[]{"phone","smartphone","dumpphone"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"phone","phone","smartphone"};

ArrayList<String> union = new ArrayList<>();
// Add elements of s2
for(String s : s2){ union.add(s); }
// Conditionally add elements of s1 (Only if they're not in s2)
for(String s : s1){ if(!union.contains(s)){ union.add(s); } }
```

Which would print:

```
phone
phone
smartphone
dumpphone
```

Comment: IMO he wants `s2` appended with `s : s1` that were not in `s2`. That's what hes expected output tells me :)

Comment: @dantuch, I think you're probably right -- updating my answer